# Cache API - Cache.addAll() encountered a network error

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I'm having an issue with the Cache API of JavaScript.
I'm developing a PWA, so I have a `serviceWorker.js` in my app.
In this `serviceWorker.js` file, I want to add files to my static cache. So I configured this to cache the static files:

```
var CACHE_STATIC_NAME = 'static-v544';
var CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME = 'dynamic-v544';
var STATIC_FILES = [
    '/css/app.css',
    '/js/app.js',
    '/js/vendor.js',
    '/js/manifest.js',
    '/js/utility.js',
    '/offline'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Installing service worker...', event);
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME)
        .then(function(cache) {
            //console.log('[Service Worker] Precaching App Shell');
            cache.addAll(STATIC_FILES)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        })
    );
});
```

Actually this is working fine, unless there seems to be trouble with the `app.js` file.
So when `cache.addAll(STATIC_FILES)` is being called, I get the error

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Cache.put() encountered a network
> error

All other files are being cached in the static cache.
I need to say, the `app.js` file is in development very big (~12 MB). It will be shrinked on production.
My questions are:

How can I investigate the error more closely? The error message is just giving me this message. Is there a way to get a more detailed error message? What can be the cause of this "network error"? Can it be, that the file is too big? Or can it be that the file is not being downloaded at all, when the service worker is trying to put it in the cache and therefore the error is being thrown?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably developing using Chrome, Firefox or another Chromium-based browser. In that case, the developer tool's [network tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) might shed some light on how exactly the network request is failing. There are quite a few guides you can find (including [this one](https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq) by the Chromium team) that explain a bit more on how to do that.

Although we lack a lot of information, my first guess is that your service worker gets installed during a compile, and that while downloading the `js/app.js` file, Webpack (or whatever you use) changes the file and causes the download to be interrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the link and your first guess. I will try to check this.

Comment: Does not work to me, I think this is a bug in chrome itself; only happens in chrome when there's not incognito mode, I think it cached something aggressively; does not occur in Firefox or any other browser, I will downgrade chrome.

Comment: Indeed, I kinda reproduced the same error using devtools. Set connection to slow 3g, when it starts downloading resource (actually starts, meaning that connection is established) - switch network to offline, I'm getting "DOMException: Cache.addAll() encountered a network error"